# Jersey 1.6 with Spring 3.0.5 using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, jersey

I'm having hard time getting Jersey to work with Spring 3.0.5. I found many person that says that they where able to make it work but I'm out of luck. I always get:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)

Is anybody able to make this work?

Thank you for your help!

---

Here is my pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

and here's the error:

> GRAVE: Exception while loading the app
>   java.lang.Exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:310)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:141)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:573)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:459)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:391)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:376)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:195)
>     at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
>     at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

Comment: Were there any nested exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and make sure there aren't any more versions of Spring getting pulled in from elsewhere.   `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId()` did not exist in Spring 2.5 but it does in 3.x.

Comment: Also do a double check to make sure those dependencies aren't hanging around your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: There is no reference to Spring 2.5 in the dependency tree. All the libs under WEB-INF are related to Spring 3.0.5.

Comment: where there any nested exceptions?   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start() definitely does not call Spring.

Comment: can I get the output of your mvn dependency:tree and also your web.xml

Comment: Here is the required information and the applicationContext.xml
http://dinoz.mobi/all.txt

Comment: Strange - I setup the example Jersey Spring application (http://blogs.sun.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/jersey_and_spring), excluded Spring 2.5 in the pom and brought in Spring 3.0.5, and did mvn glassfish:run and it ran fine.

Comment: Here's my sample project: http://rapidshare.com/files/454945656/example-spring-jersey.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ERICACM, Awesome answer.  I had the same problem using spring 3.0.5.release.  There were two jars from 2.5.6 stuck in my web-inf/lib folder.  Removing these fixed the problem.